# Saving frames in opencv without compression

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use the **imwrite()** OpenCV function. I want to save the frames with the **.TIFF** extension. The problem that I have is that the saved images are compressed so I can't use them. Any idea how I can escape this compression?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-imwrite) OpenCV only exposes a limited set of options for writing image files.
Non of which belongs to TIFF-Files.

So unless you want to use your own function or modify the OpenCV source, this is not possible. 
I would suggest using another uncompressed format for saving the frames like PXM or BMP, unless you have some specific reasons to use TIFF-Files.

Answer (score 3):

Do not mind what sietschie says. The TIFF flag is hardcoded in the opencv binaries with a LZW compression. You can just turn this off (comment it out) or change it.
In:

```
3rdparty/libtiff/tiff.h
```

Remove this line:

```
#define     COMPRESSION_LZW     5       /* Lempel-Ziv  & Welch */
```

Then compile. Presto.
Tiff options other than that are automatically set (8 bit, 16bit, color, rgb, rgba,etc) depending on your image

Comment: Just change the 5 to be 1 (COMPRESSION_NONE), otherwise you will have to fix a few places.

Answer (score 1):

```
cv::imwrite("imagen.TIFF", bayer, {cv::IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION, 1, 
cv::IMWRITE_TIFF_XDPI, 72,cv::IMWRITE_TIFF_YDPI,72});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is recompiling OpenCV or direct using libtiff, but I consider as not very good idea changing 3rdparty/libtiff/tiff.h: after this modification you can't save compressed TIFFs at all with OpenCV, and under non-windows systems you usually have separate libtiff (not as a part of OpenCV).

I suggest simpler approach (still OpenCV recompilation, but you save possibility of writing compressed tiff and don't change libtiff directly):
[saving uncompressed TIFFs with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073281/writing-16-bit-uncompressed-image-using-opencv)