# Generating a 16-bits per channel PNG file procedurally

Tags: directx, png, tiff, 16-bit

Is there any way to generate a 16-bits per channel(RGBA) PNG file using D3DX11SaveTextureToFile? 
Or any version of DirectX, any image library(C++), any image format

I tried to use the sample code here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205131(v=vs.85).aspx

and modified the function names to D3D11 version.

The program works perfectly when I set the desc.Format to DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM .

But the D3DX11SaveTextureToFile returns E_FAIL when I changed the desc.Format to DXGI_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_UNORM .

I've tried to use DevIL (developer's image library) but it doesn't support 16-bits per channel png file.

Comment: Why not use libpng directly?

Answer (score 0):

The only format which can save all texture-formats is `D3DX11_IFF_DDS`. It seems that `D3DX11SaveTextureToFile` can't save 16Bit pngs. One possibility is to extract the imagedata of your texture and save it manually with one of the possibilities (e.g. OpenCV or libpng) discussed here:  [Writing 16 bit uncompressed image using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073281/writing-16-bit-uncompressed-image-using-opencv).